# split string with trimmed whitespace C#

Tags: c#, string, split, removing-whitespace

I want to be able to split a string with ',' as a delimiter, and only trim whitespace on the sides of the resulting split. For example:

```
string str = "The, quick brown, fox";
string[] splitsWithTrim = str.split(',', also trim whitespace somehow?);
foreach (string s in splitsWithTrim)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

//output wanted:
//The
//quick brown
//fox
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` after `Split`:

```
string str = "The, quick brown, fox";
string[] splitsWithTrim = str.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();
```

Or you can change your seperator to `", "` (comma + space).It is also work for this case because there is only one `white-space` after each `comma`:

```
string[] splitsWithTrim = str.Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: If you can tolerate omitting empty entries, you can also use:
```string[] splitsWithTrim = str.Split(", ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
string str = "The, quick brown, fox"; 
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"\s*,\s*");
```

Answer (score 0):

For a Non-Linq solution, you just need to add one xtra line of code in solution

```
string str = "The, quick brown, fox";
string[] splitsWithTrim = str.split(',', also trim whitespace somehow?);
foreach (string s in splitsWithTrim)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s.Trim());
}
```